# Recursively check object field (+ nested) to be true

Tags: javascript

I have that object :

```
obj = {
    a: true,
    b: {
        c: false,
        d: true
    }
```

What's the best way to check if all fields of my object is set to true. In case all fields are true => result should be true, if not => false.

Comment: What's the best way? To do your own work and learn from your own mistakes... But I digress. Please do attempt to solve the problem yourself. There are many posts about how to recursively search an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution recursively checks if all the values are truthy.

```js
const obj = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: false,
    d: true
  }
}

const checkRecursive = (obj) => {
  return Object.values(obj).every(el => typeof el === "object" ? checkRecursive(el) : el); 
}

console.log(checkRecursive(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```js
let obj = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: false,
    d: true
  }
};

let objArray = []
function validate(obj) {
    for(const item in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[item] === 'object') {
            validate(obj[item]);
        } else  {
            objArray.push(obj[item]);
        }
    }
}

validate(obj);
// Use filter to check if there are any false value.
console.log(objArray.filter( item => !item).length === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own recursive function with logic similar to the example below:

```js
const obj = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: {
      d: true,
      e: {
        f: false
      }
    },
    g: false,
    h: {
      i: false,
      j: true,
      k: {
        l: false
      }
    }
  },
  m: {
    n: true,
    o: false,
    p: {
      q: {
        r: {
          s: {
            t: true,
            u: {
              v: false,
              w: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function deepSearchForValue(o, searchValue) {
  let found = false;
  const level = [];
  const keys = [];

  function deepSearch(o) {
    for (let [prop, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
      if (value === searchValue) {
        found = true;
        keys.push(`${level.join('.')}.${prop}`);
      } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
        level.push(prop);
        deepSearch(value);
        level.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  deepSearch(o);

  return [found, keys];
}

const [hasFalseValues, falseValueKeys] = deepSearchForValue(obj, false);
if (hasFalseValues) {
  falseValueKeys.forEach(s => console.info(`false found at ${s}`));
}
```